# Why does running MAKE from a Java application result in an error message?

Tags: java, linux, shell

I try to run Linux shell command from Java. The commands work fine directly on the shell, but one always crash.
I have a makefile and I try to run the make through Java.

My Java code:

```
String command = "make generate FILE=" + name ;
String [] envp = { } ;
File dir = new File ( System.getProperty("user.dir")) ;
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command,envp,dir);
proc.waitFor();

BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
String line = "";
while ((line=buf.readLine())!=null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

My makefile:

```
generate:
    llvm-as -f VSOP_Executable/$(FILE).ll -o $(FILE).bc
        llc $(FILE).bc
        gcc -c $(FILE).s -o $(FILE).o
        gcc $(FILE).o -o $(FILE) -no-pie
```

It always crash at the last line, where I try to generate an executable.
The error:

> makefile:47: recipe for target 'generate' failed

Comment: *I have a makefile and I try to run the make through java.* **Why**?

Comment: Have you checked your environment variables? PATH, LDLIBRARY, etc.?

Comment: In fact, that's the problem, since you're setting your environment to empty, so you won't be able to find llvm-as, llc, or gcc, and gcc won't be able to link.

Comment: `Process::waitFor` *Causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the process represented by this Process object has terminated.*  Why would you expect to be able to read the inputstream of a terminated process? Am I missing something?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The make file was already made. Even if i try to run the command directly in the code, without the make file. Same issue. Last command doest not work.

Comment: @Max_Thom Still sounds like a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/243725) to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved as [Paul Hicks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3195526/paul-hicks) wrote in his comment. The reason was clearing all environment variables.

I changed the code and removed the empty `envp`. It seems to work now.

```
String cmd = "make generateVSOP FILE=" + name;
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = run.exec(cmd);
pr.waitFor();

BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
String line = "";
while ((line=buf.readLine())!=null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```